# How can I control indicator and webapps in unity?

Tags: unity, 12.10, indicator, webapps

I do not clearly understand the behavior of webapps and indicator in ubuntu 12.10.

For example I installed webapps (google calendar) and an indicator (weather) from official repository. How can I use them ? Where are they ?

Moreover, I do not understand why thunderbird is not a part of the envelope icon ?

Comment: Please split your Thunderbird question into a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Web apps are basically launchers on your system, along with some code that is run in your browser to provide notifications and other system integration features.

The web apps you have installed are stored in `~/.local/share/applications` and in some cases in `/usr/share/applications` (this is in the case of applications you install using the Ubuntu Software Centre). You can search for Webapps from the Dash and add them to your launcher as well, but you cannot really control them as such by default.

There is an application called [Unsettings](https://launchpad.net/unsettings) which allows you to enable and disable specific web applications, or you can do so manually by removing their `.desktop` files.

[image: Unsettings]

Comment: Today there is not any "official" application to do that ?

Comment: @Ger not _yet_. As far as I understand, it is planned, but not implemented yet.